# metabolic heat generation and exercise intensity

Tags: metabolism, theoretical-biology, skin, temperature

Is there a relationship between bio heat equation [(found here)](http://www.academia.edu/7350650/Finite_Element_Analysis_of_One_Dimensional_Bio-Heat_Transfer_in_Human_Tissue) and exercise intensity as described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabolic_equivalent)
That is I am trying to include the effect from exercises to the tempertaure variation in skin. I am trying include the term $Q_e$ which measures the heat generated from exercises,
 to the known bio heat equation
 [image]
So that it would be modified as
[image].
So I would like to know if there is a relationship between **metabolic heat generation and exercise intensity**.